# Fixed div does not place below another div but rather over it

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with an inferior `div` that contains five images and it's floating with `position: fixed;`. But over it there is a text, so when the screen is too vertical small the fixed `div` place over and hiding the text.

**This is how is supposed to show:**
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3vlNJIDJA6RcGxVRlJfazhpZnc/view

**This is how is showing on small screen:**
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3vlNJIDJA6RTVNrdTEtQ21tUE0/view

`margin-top: xxpx;` doesn't work.

The live page: http://www.metamorfosisteam.com/

(It's a wordpress theme builded over bootstrap2)

**EDIT**
Here a fiddle where is what I think is the basic problem, when the scroll ends the fixed div ends over the last component of the other div. I want the scroll doesn't end untill the fixed div doesn't cover the another div. 
http://jsfiddle.net/miguel_crespo/xkrw4jgq

**I appreciate your help :)**

Comment: My internet won't load the images you've provided, But I'd suggest have you tried changing the z-index values?

Comment: I changed the images server

Comment: Yeah that's better now, I think it seems that your problem is your not using a responsive design? Do you have fixed width and height properties in the CSS?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Can you take a little look to the page using the google chrome's console?

Comment: Try top:xxpx; Margin don't work with position:absolute; or add float:left your class.

Comment: I tried but nothing. Here a fiddle where is what I think is the basic problem, when the scroll ends the fixed div ends over the last component of the other div. I want the scroll doesn't end untill the fixed div doesn't cover the another div. http://jsfiddle.net/miguel_crespo/xkrw4jgq/

Comment: Give a padding-bottom to the `.absolute` with value equal to the height of the fixed div.